# Power Management on a Seagate External drive

Tags: usb, hard-drive, xubuntu, power-management

I am using a **Silicon Power Armor A30 USB 3.0** external drive on a **Xubuntu 22.04** system.
The hard disk Silicon Power has put inside is a **Seagate ST1000LM035-1RK172**.

This drive's only issue is that it spins down every 5 minutes approximately if it detects no access. The system though checks the USB port in regular intervals and this spins the disk back up again and again. This behavior is the same whether the disk is mounted or not. I'm pretty sure that this power cycle will eventually harm the drive and seriously reduce its life.

I have already tried both `hdparm -B 255 /dev/sdX` and `hdparm -S 0 /dev/sdx`. Both commands report that they are carried out successfully but the disk keeps spinning down the same way as if no command has been given.

Does anyone know if there is any other way to disable this power management issue?

Thank you.